# Nice formulas for the lambda invariant of an elliptic curve

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, hyperbolic-geometry

Where can I find some nice formulas for the lambda invariant of an elliptic curve? I vaguely recall there's a nice product formula in terms of $q$, but a Google search didn't give me much. Also, are there other formulas that express the $\lambda$ function in terms of $q$ or give a precise formula for the coefficients of its $q$-expansion?

At the moment I have two books at my disposal: Silverman's *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, and Diamond and Shurman. Silverman gives nice formulas for the $j$-invariant, but I can't find much on the $\lambda$-invariant, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/23.17.E4)?

Comment: I have never seen that! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Make sure it matches the definition given in your books; I'm not sure what normalization they use there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to settle this: there are a number of formulae for the elliptic lambda function that can be found in the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/23.15), the [Wolfram Functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseEllipticNomeQ/), or [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseNome.html). (Yes, the modular lambda function and the inverse nome are more or less the same thing.)